# Getting nonce too high on RPC debug_traceTransaction call

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, geth-debugging

i am trying to get the transaction trace (similar to the one found as `Geth trace_2` on etherscan) and to do so i try to use the `debug_traceTransaction` but each time with any transaction hash i am trying i get the error :

```
{"code":-32000,"message":"transaction <hash> failed: nonce too high: address <address>, tx: 11489 state: 0"}
```

the hash and address are related to other transactions in the same block as my transaction. I know that `debug_traceTransaction` tries to replay the same transactions that happened before my transaction (only from the smae block, i presume) but getting nonce too high here seems to be counterintuitive since the nonce on any adddress only goes up.

how can i use `debug_traceTransaction` without triggiring this kind of errors.

Comment: you should set nonce to the amount of transactions that already have been sent with the account, it is the consecutive number of now many transactions you are sending

Comment: i am not launching those transactions, i am trying to get the debug of my transaction and the other txs are just in the same block

Comment: well it is obvious that you are debugging your own transaction, but apparently you don't understand that you are setting a wrong `Nonce` on it

Comment: @Nulik i am not setting nonce at all. and the transaction in the error is not my transaction and the same for the address. the error transaction happens to be in the same block as my own transaction. i am a bit confused here really.

Comment: this is not true. `debug.traceTransaction()` does not replay transactions of others, only your transaction is replayed. you can check this in `eth/tracers/api.go` line number 717 : `msg, vmctx, statedb, err := api.backend.StateAtTransaction(ctx, block, int(index), reexec)` , it fetches intermediate Root from transaction that was executed just before yours

Comment: @Nulik i saw that info in the official docs :
The traceTransaction debugging method will attempt to run the transaction in the exact same manner as it was executed on the network. It will replay any transaction that may have been executed prior to this one before it will finally attempt to execute the transaction that corresponds to the given hash.

https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/ns-debug#debug_tracetransaction

Comment: that's how they explain it to people so they can understand easily. In reality there is no need to replay anything because there is a state root hash stored from previous transaction, so in the actual implementation there is no need to replay all transactions again. I have pointed you to the sources that clearly show it.

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/c6195623138a995e5c8ec700ba2b0aa3f605951d/eth/tracers/api.go#L710

Comment: if it would be replaying prevoius transactions there would be a `for()` loop somewhere, like for example here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/c6195623138a995e5c8ec700ba2b0aa3f605951d/core/state_processor.go#L76
where is the `for()` loop in `tracers/api.go`????

Comment: @Nulik suppose you are right, why am i getting an error for nonce of a different transaction and address of the ones i am trying to trace ?

Comment: the only reason for this error is that someone set incorrect nonce on the transaction: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/c6195623138a995e5c8ec700ba2b0aa3f605951d/core/state_transition.go#L215

Comment: as for tracing, anyone can trace transactions of everyone (as long as they are within 128 blocks from the head block, or if you have archival node)

Comment: It sounds like this is clearly a bug in geth, as the transaction was already mined into a block the nonce should be fine.